# Google tag manager: how to fire an event at the end of the user's session?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to fire and event at the very end of the user's session. What's the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that. Session in GA is determined by Google and is not changeable.

Comment: Sorry, I may have explained in a wrong way my problem. I don´t want to change when the session ends. I want to find out when it ends and then fire the tag.

Comment: As I said, you can't do that. Google tracks sessions and performs all session-related calculations automatically (visits, time on site, etc.). What do you want to find out by creating your own end of session event?

Comment: I came here with the sames question. I want to know which user logged in at what time and for how long, and I want this info in my web application, so it would need to be sent to some kind of web hook.

Comment: You can add events to your website that track explicit login and logout events (attached to login and logout buttons, links, etc.), but you can't determine or fire specific "session" events. Also, tracking specific user information in GA is prohibited by GA terms of service. You can use your own application to track and monitor these events. You will have to ensure that you are compliant with local, national, and international laws and regulations regarding the storage and use of personal information.